# How to specify query parameter in Lucene search syntax?

Tags: api, request, lucene, musicbrainz

I want to make a get request to this https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_API/Search music-API.I want it to search for the name of the album and the release format. The release format should be vinyl. You can search for these things in the query-part of the request. It works fine if I don't specify any format but when I do specify one it doesn't register and still shows other release-formats such as CD and Digital. This is the Url I'm using to do my request: https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release?query=depeche%20mode%20music%20for%20the%20massesANDformat%3AVinyl&fmt=json&limit=10
Does anybody know how I have to change my URL so that it only shows me the vinyl-formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the `Format` field is based on a constrained list of pre-defined values - as shown in the [release format](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Release/Format) listing page.

It is therefore possible that the Lucene index has defined this field as a [`StringField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_2/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) rather than a [`TextField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_2/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html).

A `StringField` is defined as:

> A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is indexed as a single token.

This means that you cannot search for `vinyl`. You need to use the exact value, which can be one of:

```
7" Vinyl
10" Vinyl
12" Vinyl
```

So, to account for this, you can build that part of the Lucene query as follows:

```
AND (format:"7\" vinyl" OR format:"10\" vinyl" format:"12\" vinyl")
```

The text values are surrounded by `"`s to ensure the entire term is treated as a single token in the query (to exactly match the single token in the index).

The backslashes are used to escape the `"` in the text.

The overall Lucene query therefore becomes this:

```
title:"music for the masses" AND artist:"depeche mode" AND (format:"7\" vinyl" OR format:"10\" vinyl" OR format:"12\" vinyl")
```

And when added to the URL, it becomes this:

```
https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release?query=title:"music for the masses" AND artist:"depeche mode" AND (format:"7\" vinyl" OR format:"10\" vinyl" OR format:"12\" vinyl")&fmt=json
```

I pasted the above into my browser query bar, and I got 8 release objects returned in the JSON response.

When the URL is URL-encoded, it ends up as follows:

```
https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release?query=title:%22music%20for%20the%20masses%22%20AND%20artist:%22depeche%20mode%22%20AND%20(format:%227\%22%20vinyl%22%20OR%20format:%2210\%22%20vinyl%22%20OR%20format:%2212\%22%20vinyl%22)&fmt=json
```

---

I mentioned at the beginning that *it is therefore possible* that the format field (and probably several others) is indexed as a string field. I do not know this as a fact - but it is the only way I can explain why my query works and your does not. So I think it's a reasonable assumption - but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for that great comment. It really cleared things up for me and everything works as intended... thanks